# Show/Hide Table Rows with Javascript When Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to reveal the lower half of an html table when a user clicks on the word 'toggle'.

I've been trying to use JavaScript but haven't had much luck.  I've assigned each row a class of '`hideThis`' and set it's display to '`none`' as well as created a function to to reveal the rows when toggle is clicked.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function toggle() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("hideThis").style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hideThis").style.display = 'table-row';
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hideThis").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<span onClick="toggle();">toggle</span>


<table border="1" bordercolor="#51555E" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr border="0">
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; padding-left:15px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold" width="250">Features</th>
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:center; padding-left:5px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold" width="119">Test</th>
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:center; padding-left:5px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold" width="105">Test</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody border="0">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px">
                <span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://discover.nuemd.com/l/12422/2014-12-05/pplw5/12422/116874/grey_circle_x.png" alt="No" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">M-F 8am-9pm. Email and phone</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display:none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; line-height: 200%;"><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                Test
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
               Test
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Test</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to hide all elements with class `hideThis`, or just a specific one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements with a
   specified class.
2. You have to iterate each element and set the visibility

```js
function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("hideThis");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display == 'none')
      x[i].style.display = 'table-row';
    else
      x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```html
<span onClick="toggle();">toggle</span>


<table border="1" bordercolor="#51555E" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="400" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr border="0">
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family:tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; padding-left:15px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold" width="250">Features</th>
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:center; padding-left:5px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold" width="119">Test</th>
              <th bgcolor="#51555E" height="35" style="color:#ffffff; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:center; padding-left:5px; font-size:15px; font-weight:bold" width="105">Test</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody border="0">
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Platform Independent</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, Android</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">Windows 7 or higher and Mac</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Multiple Data Centers</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">One datacenter</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Reported Uptime.</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">99.99%</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">99%</span> 
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Years in Business</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">22</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">6</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">HIPAA Compliant Clearinghouse.</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://discover.nuemd.com/l/12422/2014-12-05/pplw5/12422/116874/grey_circle_x.png" alt="No" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Claims First Pass Acceptance Rate.</span>
                <br>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">99.98%</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">90%</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px">
                <span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Personalized Training Options</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://discover.nuemd.com/l/12422/2014-12-05/pplw5/12422/116874/grey_circle_x.png" alt="No" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Phone, Email and Live Chat support with 24/7 Access.</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">M-F 8am-9pm. Email and phone</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">EHR Flexibility</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">In-house Billers and Coders</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display:none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Mobile Apps</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">iOS and Android</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; line-height: 200%;"><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">iOS only</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Patient Portal</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Internal Messaging</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Free Updates</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">ICD-10 Ready</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Enhanced Reporting</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; ">
                <img src="http://nue.md/XsRXeL" alt="Yes" style="width:20px; height:20px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Software Advice Rating</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">4.4 star rating</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">3.7 star rating</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="hideThis" style="display: none;">
              <td style="padding-left:15px; padding-top: 10px"><span style="color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left; font-size:18px; ">Capterra Rating</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">4.5 star rating</span>
              </td>
              <td style=" text-align:center; color:#595959; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; "><span style=" color:#595959; font-family: tahoma, sans-serif; text-align:left;  font-size:13px;">3 star rating</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```